# Merge pasted into Excel cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a table in Word, each row is a few lines of text (shift + enter).
When I copy the table to Excel every line of copy to my own line. You can copy (each line where it was used (shift + enter)) to one row in Excel?

*My table in Word.*

[image: word]

*Copied table to Excel.*

[image: excel]

I want to Row1 Text - Row1 TextC was A1. I know I can merge, but I have a big table and looking for solutions, which will accelerate.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't 'easy' presuming you're comfortable with excel you're going to need to either use the VBA environment or have a few additional columns.

One way would be to identify the 'top' and 'bottom' of each Row by; in column C (starting from C2, C1 is always "top") `=if(left(c2,4)<>left(c2,1),"Top", if(left(c2,4)<>left(c3,4),"Bottom","middle"`

Then in column D (and cell locking is important, also assumes it goes to row 100, you will need to change this)

`if(or(C1={"bottom","middle"}),"",$A1 & " - " & index($A1:$A$100,match("bottom", $A1:$A$100,0)))`

This will give you a list, with breaks in which you can either remove by copying and pasting column D to a new sheet as values, pressing F5 and removing blanks.  The other way would be to remove duplicates from the pasted list, and then take out the blank wherever it appears.

There may be more efficient ways of doing this, but it's a pretty unique question!

Maudise